# exporting HTML table to outlook

Tags: html

My question is regarding exporting of HTML table to Microsoft Outlook. On the click of a button I want to export the entire HTML table to Microsoft Outlook's email body.

The code that I have tried is sending the entire HTML code to Outlook's body, which is not required.

I want to send the entire table with the borders and columns and data also. Please tell me if this is possible?

Comment: How does this relate to SharePoint?

Comment: dude I want to export sharepoint list to Microsoft outlook body, in the same structure as it is displayed in sharepoint web page. I was trying it first on simple HTML table but at the end of the day it is exporting only all the tags from the <table> tag to </table>. I want the table structure in the outlooks body.